# How to call jQuery table sorter on a table which is getting loaded dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, tablesorter

I have a jsp file where I make an ajax call which returns back some html. Now I fill it in a  div. One element of html result is my table. So, until I do ajax call this table wont be contained. So, I am not able to use the table sorter. For example:

I wrote some thing like this:

```
 $('#sortByDate').on('click',(function(){

         sort = [[ 7, 0]];
    $('#resultsTable').trigger("sorton",[sort]);     
    });

 }));
```

I am getting some exception like:

> "**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '7' of undefined** "

I tried live query and got same error. I am able to use the table sorter successfully in the js file which has this resultsTable. But all i want is to call table sorter from other js file which gets this table dynamically.

I am looking for something like jquery live function to automagically do it for me..

Please share your views.

Thanks

Comment: How and when are you initializing jquery table sorter?

Comment: Ok. say there are two js files. parent and child. parent makes ajax call. so, now server fills the child.jsp and sends it back. so i am doing the jquery initialization in child.jsp. In child.jsp i do similar sort based on coloumn 8. I dont have any problem. Now in parent.jsp user wants to sort by column 7. so i tried to do as above but failed.

Comment: is this the plugin you are using?  I'm trying to figure out if you are initializing the table sorter after your ajax call. http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: yes... that is the plugin... i guess i am initialzing it in child.jsp because the table is getting sorted as i want it to... after sorting i am getting all the html from child.js and loading into parent.js

Comment: Are you using the load method to load the html into your parent page?  Are you importing jQuery in both pages?  Can you show the head of both pages?  Maybe some example code of both which is relevant to the problem/issue.

Comment: Hi, i noticed something which is causing the issue... i tried to look into length of table after ajax call from parent.jsp and it shows up as zero. so it might be why table sorter is failing. but not able to figure out how to get the table into parent.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19175/discussion-between-ravi-and-wirey)